# local storage data resets after refreshing page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I am trying to make a cart page for my website. After adding the product from the product page when I change the quantity of product or delete the product on the cart page front end works well and changes are also reflected in local storage but after refreshing the page the quantity resets to the default. However, after visiting any other page and then coming back to the cart page, all functions work perfectly.
I am using this code :

```
localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
```

This is the code remaining code

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { CART_ADD_ITEM, CART_REMOVE_ITEM } from '../constants/cartConstants'

export const addToCart = (id, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)

  dispatch({
    type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
    payload: {
      product: data._id,
      name: data.name,
      image: data.image,
      price: data.price,
      countInStock: data.countInStock,
      qty,
    },
  })

  localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
}

export const removeFromCart = (id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({
    type: CART_REMOVE_ITEM,
    payload: id,
  })

  localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
}
```

Comment: Add more code. Where do you use `localStorage.removeItem` ?

Comment: I haven't used ```localStorage.removeItem``` anywhere

Comment: Try to console.log() `getState().cart` each before `localStorage.setItem()`

Comment: Could you please add some more code? Seems like you are storing the default value in the `localStorage` on each refresh.

Answer (score 0):

When page refreshs, in any place of your code, yoy should use `localStorage.getItem` to get the data previously saved in storage with `localStorage.setItem` , parse it with JSON.parse, and then dispatch in redux state the parsed cartItems array with a new action (CART_SAVE_ALL_ITEMS for example).